# Rounded Column in custom Button Control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010, c#-to-vb.net

I'm trying to create a class for custom button control that will have 2 ingradient top and bottom color with rounded corners. 
Below is the code that gives me two gradients color on top and bottom. However, I'm facing some issue with this where mouse hover property is not working and image also not showing (since new ingredients color overlaping the button text and image that is hidden in the back of ingradients color)

Can somebody help me with this control where all the control should work like they work with windows button control in addition to gradient color and rounded corners?

Please let me know in case you require any additional information.

Thanks in advance.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Class MyButton
    Inherits Button

    Private m_TopColor As Color = Color.LightGreen
    Private m_BottomColor As Color = Color.Orange

    Public Property TopColor As Color
        Get
            Return m_TopColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            m_TopColor = value
            Me.Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property BottomColor As Color
        Get
            Return m_BottomColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            m_BottomColor = value
            Me.Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        Using lgb As LinearGradientBrush = New LinearGradientBrush(Me.ClientRectangle, m_TopColor, m_BottomColor, 90.0F)
            Using textBrush As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor)
                Using format As StringFormat = New StringFormat()
                    format.Alignment = GetHorizontalAlignment()
                    format.LineAlignment = GetVerticalAlignment()
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(lgb, Me.ClientRectangle)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, textBrush, Me.ClientRectangle, format)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Function GetVerticalAlignment() As StringAlignment
        Return CType(Math.Log(Me.TextAlign, 2D) / 4, StringAlignment)
    End Function

    Private Function GetHorizontalAlignment() As StringAlignment
        Return CType(Math.Log(Me.TextAlign, 2D) Mod 4, StringAlignment)
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

customize a rounded button,code:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D


    Class MyButton
        Inherits Button

        Private m_TopColor As Color = Color.LightGreen
        Private m_BottomColor As Color = Color.Orange

        Public Property TopColor As Color
            Get
                Return m_TopColor
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Color)
                m_TopColor = value
                Me.Invalidate()
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property BottomColor As Color
            Get
                Return m_BottomColor
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Color)
                m_BottomColor = value
                Me.Invalidate()
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub New()
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
            FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
            FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)
            FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent
            FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent
            BackColor = Color.Transparent
            Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom

            AddHandler Me.MouseMove, AddressOf MyMouseMove
            AddHandler Me.MouseLeave, AddressOf MyMouseLeave

        End Sub
        Private Sub MyMouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        End Sub

        Private Sub MyMouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)

        End Sub

        Private Sub Draw(ByVal rectangle As Rectangle, ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal cusp As Boolean)

            Dim span As Integer = 2
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
            Dim myLinearGradientBrush As LinearGradientBrush = New LinearGradientBrush(Me.ClientRectangle, m_TopColor, m_BottomColor, 90.0F)


            g.FillPath(myLinearGradientBrush, DrawRoundRect(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y, rectangle.Width - span, rectangle.Height - 1, 20))
        End Sub
        Private Function DrawRoundRect(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer, ByVal radius As Integer) As GraphicsPath
            Dim gp As GraphicsPath = New GraphicsPath()
            gp.AddArc(x, y, radius, radius, 180, 90)
            gp.AddArc(width - radius, y, radius, radius, 270, 90)
            gp.AddArc(width - radius, height - radius, radius, radius, 0, 90)
            gp.AddArc(x, height - radius, radius, radius, 90, 90)
            gp.CloseAllFigures()
            Return gp
        End Function

        Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnPaint(e)

            Draw(e.ClipRectangle, e.Graphics, False)

        End Sub

        Private Function GetVerticalAlignment() As StringAlignment
            Return CType(Math.Log(Me.TextAlign, 2D) / 4, StringAlignment)
        End Function

        Private Function GetHorizontalAlignment() As StringAlignment
            Return CType(Math.Log(Me.TextAlign, 2D) Mod 4, StringAlignment)
        End Function

    End Class
```

Comment: I didn't see any change in this control, I didn't find any property for round corner and button image in the control. Is there something, I have to change in code to make the button corner round and to show button icon image?

Comment: You can modify the 30 in the code below to modify the fillet   g.FillPath(myLinearGradientBrush, DrawRoundRect(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y, rectangle.Width - span, rectangle.Height - 1, 30))

Comment: Again, I'm looking a button control that have a round corner, can have Top and bottom color, can have button image and text. In the above code corners are showing round and top & bottom color is also showing but I'm not able to see any text and button image on the button because these are overlaping by rectangle which you added.

Comment: You need to do it all by yourself (drawing the image and the text as well) when you override the OnPaint event. The OS won't do it for you.